# Non-equivalent distances on $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: metric-spaces

> Let $\vert x-y\vert$ be the usual distance over $\Bbb{R}$ and $\gamma(x,y)=\Phi(d(x,y))$ where $\Phi(t)=\frac{t}{1+t}$.
>
> I would like to prove that the two distance are not equivalent.

I now the definition to be equivalent is to find two constant $\alpha,\beta$ such that 
$$
\alpha\cdot\gamma(x,y)\le d(x,y)\le \beta\cdot\gamma(x,y).
$$

Effort: Perchance arguing by contradiction.
$$
d(x,y)\le \beta\cdot\gamma(x,y)
\Longleftrightarrow \vert x-y\vert\le \beta \frac{\vert x-y\vert}{1+\vert x-y\vert}
$$
It can be rewritten as 
$$
1+\vert x-y\vert\le\beta \quad\text{for}\quad x\ne y
$$

Now I am tempted to say it's impossible because $x\mapsto\vert x-y\vert+1$ cannot be bounded by a constant (increasing/decreasing argument). Is it correct?

*Additional question if I'm right.*  What assumptions can be introduced to find a function such that these distances are equivalent?

Comment: That's perfectly fine. Regarding the other question: If you chose a bounded subset of $\mathbb R$ (say an interval) you may be able to get somewhere ;)

Comment: @AlexR Great, thank you very much. I will search.

Comment: Happy to help. Note that the metric is translation invariant so you may assume WLOG $y=0$ and look at $|x|$ vs $\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}$. A hint to why they are not equvalent (even on intervals) is that the derivative of the latter blows up near $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your definition of equivalence of metrics, the metrics $d$ and $\gamma(x,y)=\Phi(d(x,y))$ are equivalent if and only if there exist $\alpha,\beta$ such that 
$$\alpha t\le \Phi(t)\le \beta t,\quad t\ge 0 \tag1$$
As you demonstrated, $\Phi(t)/t\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$, violating (1).

A sufficient condition for (1) to hold is that $\Phi'$ is bounded between two positive constants (and $\Phi(0)=0$). But in practice, it is usually easiest to check (1) directly.